# Search product with woocommerce REST API by sku

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I have to create a service in order to publish products to a wordpress via woocommerce REST API.
We are creating products in site by using the batch update "function".
All nice and fine, but I cannot search if a product already exist in order to not multiply (or get error on insert) by anything else except the id.
Is there a way to search for a product by sku?
tks

Answer (score 1):

You can by using the GET method.
`'products' with param sku`
very important to use "GET", if you use POST you add one empty product in word press.

Answer (score 0):

its old question, but for future viewers here is solution

```
function CreateOrUpdate ($product , $sku) {
    
    $pid = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($sku); 
    $updateResp = Update_Product($product,$pid);
    
    if ($updateResp -> code == "rest_no_route" or $updateResp -> code == "woocommerce_rest_product_invalid_id"){    
          $resp =  Create_Product($product);
          return $resp;
        //       return json_encode(array('update' => $updateResp));
    } else {
        // return json_encode(array('update' => $updateResp));
        return json_encode(array('update' => 'success'));
    }
    
}
```

create your product

```
function Create_Product($product){
 // create your product here
}
```

update product

```
function Update_Product($product){
     // update your product here
}
```

$product is the information base on which you will create or update.am getting it from an api